# Docker-compose cant find .sh file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sh, gunicorn, fastapi

I am going to run a shell script inside a docker-compose entrypoint. But when i do `docker-compose up`, the gunicorn is starting but it **cant** found the shell script. Everything works fine without the shell script. But I just want to add the shell script because i need to set some parameters.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-container:
    image: my_image:latest
    volumes:
      - ${LOGDIR}:/app/log/
      - ${SCRIPTS}:/app/scripts/
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:80
    entrypoint: 
      - /bin/sh
      - /app/scripts/api_reload.sh
```

This is inside `api_reload.sh`

```
# !/usr/bin/env

gunicorn app.inf.api.api_pks:app \
    -b 0.0.0.0:80 \
    -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
    --timeout 1000
```

This is the error info

```
Recreating information-extraction1 ... done
Attaching to information-extraction_my-container_1
: not found_1  | /app/scripts/api_reload.sh: 3: /app/scripts/api_reload.sh:
my-container_1  | [2021-12-10 00:01:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
my-container_1  | [2021-12-10 00:01:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8)
my-container_1  | [2021-12-10 00:01:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: sync
my-container_1  | [2021-12-10 00:01:20 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
my-container_1  | 2021-12-10 00:01:21,130 - INFO - api - <module>, line 50: PREDICTION HAS BEEN STARTED
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the script accidentally have DOS line endings?

Comment: @DavidMaze can you explain more about it? i'm using windows btw. I had make sure that the script doesnt have any extra char/space/symbol

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct however since the dir is mounted you have to ensure that the user running the container is able to see it.

I've reproduced a short example and I can confirm that it works.

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── scripts
    └── api_reload.sh
```

`api_reload.sh` content

```sh
# !/usr/bin/env

echo "entry point!"
```

`docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
services:
  my-container:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/:/app/scripts/
    entrypoint: 
      - /bin/sh
      - /app/scripts/api_reload.sh
```

The entry point is executed when the container is started.

```sh
docker-compose up
# Starting entrypoint_my-container_1 ... done
# Attaching to entrypoint_my-container_1
# my-container_1  | entry point!
# entrypoint_my-container_1 exited with code 0
```